# Android XML representation in eclipse and on phone different

Tags: android, xml, textview

[xml files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bco95u8d0wozski/j7D13-Gbq-)

And this should show Text view on top of screen, and all the other components under it. But when i run application on phone all other components come up, and Text view is under (and its the size that was specified). Even worse thing happens on landscape preview. Text view should be on left sied and everything else on right but again everything else is on top and text view on bottom. Does anyone seem to know whats the problem?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Please post the layout XML.  Both, if you have one in landscape as well.

Comment: in dropbox link. Sorry, for that but i couldn't fix identation on both files, to paste code here directly on post.

Comment: come on people someone surely knows what's wrong here...